# Android fragment can be clicked when hidden (Maps v2 + Sliding Drawer issue)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

Interesting issue here guys, which I hope somebody can shed some light on.

I currently have a Maps v2 fragment with a Sliding Drawer (deprecated - I know) on the same screen. Once the user is finished with their tasks, they can pull the sliding draw up and click "finish". This makes use of SupportFragmentManager and I basically end up replacing the contents of the screen with a brand new fragment.

However, the user is still able to click content on the Sliding Drawer even though it has been replaced with the new fragment. Any hints?

Below is the skeletal structure of the responsible code:

**activity_map.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_map">

    <LinearLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
            android:name="com.foo.fragment.MapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer>
        ...
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
...
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.activity_map, newFragment, TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: `transaction.replace(R.id.activity_map, newFragment, TAG);` you are trying to replace fragment on a layout container(RelativeLayout) while there doesn't exist any fragment!

Comment: you should make the layout content of `activity_map.xml` as part of a fragment layout then you would be able to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar But I do have a map fragment in the above container. I need an activity around the sliding drawer and my map fragment, and then I need to replace both the drawer and the map and fill the screen with another fragment. What is the best way to do this? –

Comment: The current easiest will be open a new activity if this suits your architecture! Otherwise you have to follow the above advise!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Ok, starting a new activity is complete overkill for what I need to do, so could you please post a revised activity_map.xml below in the answers? I will implement your first suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and most elegant solution in this case was to set clickable="true" on my new fragment in its static xml layout file.

The next step was to manually associate listeners to the new buttons and text edits on this fragment.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You should try to do like this
`activity_map.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/container>

</FrameLayout>
```

`fragment_map.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_map">

    <LinearLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
            android:name="com.foo.fragment.MapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer>
        ...
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now inside your activity you should first start a new fragment (lets say AMapFragment) having layout `fragment_map` inside FrameLayout (activity_map.xml). Please note now the below code will be part of your fragment (AMapFragment)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.activity_map, newFragment, TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And change this line `transaction.replace(R.id.activity_map, newFragment, TAG);` to `transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, TAG);`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Will I run into trouble having embedded fragments (Google Map V2 + Sliding Drawer) inside a parent fragment?

Comment: No you shouldn't because there are no nested fragments

Comment: Ok, will test this out this evening. Are nested fragments for a situation like this standard practise, or should I open a new activity and initialise it will all my variables from the previous activity + fragments.  I want to get the design correct from the ground up.  I'm happy to implement either solution.

Comment: Nested Fragments are ok to use if that suites your app and design architecture! Note you have to use getChildfragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager for nested fragments!